# CoreLocation: didUpdateToLocation not getting called

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-location

I'm currently developing my first CoreLocation-based app and I have a problem with the CLLocationManager not calling delegate methods. Here's the class I'm using:

```
//
//  LocationGetter.h
//  whatsunderme
//
//  Created by Tobias Timpe on 16.06.12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 tobisoft. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@protocol LocationGetterDelegate
@required
- (void) newPhysicalLocation:(CLLocation *)location;
@end

@interface LocationGetter : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
   CLLocationManager *locationManager;
   id delegate;
} 

- (void)startUpdates;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
@end

//
//  LocationGetter.m
//  whatsunderme
//
//  Created by Tobias Timpe on 16.06.12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 tobisoft. All rights reserved.
//

#import "LocationGetter.h"

@implementation LocationGetter

@synthesize locationManager, delegate;
BOOL didUpdate = NO;

- (void)startUpdates {
    if (self.locationManager == nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"Starting Location Updates");
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error");
}

// Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manage didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)
newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
        NSLog(@"new Location found");
    didUpdate = YES;
    // Disable future updates to save power.
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    [self.delegate newPhysicalLocation:newLocation];

}


@end
```

Neither the didUpdateToLocation nor the didFailWithError methods are getting called. I don't know why.
Hope you can help me with this since I've been trying to figure out what the problem is for 2 hours.

Comment: Is this as simple as setting delegate = self in your method? I can't tell from your header if it's properly implemented.

Comment: @EvanDyson It's there: `self.locationManager.delegate = self;`

Comment: Ah, didn't scroll. Apologies. Appears okay, but reviewing more.

Comment: Can you verify that location services are enabled and the app is authorized.  Use `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` and `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` to check the status of both

Comment: Well, I have tested this in both the Simulator and on my iPhone, both have location services enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh, stupid me!

I forgot to declare the variable for the LocationGetter instance in the .h file instead of the .m file!

Answer (score 2):

Use my code, it should work for you...

First ensure you are using the protocol by adding the following, for example to your AppDelegate or whichever controller you want CoreLocation to work in...

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Create some properties, I also use a custom method but you don't have too...

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *currentLocation;

- (void)startUpdatingCurrentLocation;
```

Then in your implementation file call the custom method to start CL

```
// start location services
[self startUpdatingCurrentLocation];
```

Below is the code to my custom method.

```
- (void)startUpdatingCurrentLocation
{    
  // if location services are on
  if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
  {
    // if location services are restricted do nothing
    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted )
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Determining your current location cannot be performed at this time because location services are enabled but restricted." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else 
    {
        if(!locationManager_)
        {
            locationManager_ = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            [locationManager_ setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
            [locationManager_ setDelegate:self];
            [locationManager_ setDistanceFilter:5.0f];          // measured in meters
            [locationManager_ setHeadingFilter:5];              // measured in degrees
            [locationManager_ setPurpose:@"Enabling location services is required in order to automatically determine the location of yada yada yada..."];
        }

        [locationManager_ startUpdatingLocation];
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Determining your current location cannot be performed at this time because location services are not enabled." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me adding the string "location-services" to UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities array in Info.plist solved the problem.

Read the documentation here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1

The value for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities is an array of strings indicating the features that your app requires. There are two strings relevant to location services:

Include the location-services string if you require location services in general.
Include the gps string if your app requires the accuracy offered only by GPS hardware.